# duplication in parsing spring context

Tags: spring, configuration

Nowadays I've got to know spring mvc.
exactly about

```
context:component-scan
```

and

```
mvc:annotation-driven
```

and

```
tx:annotation-driven
```

in spring config xml

Here is my question.
As I know, "context:component-scan" scans all beans.
and As I heard, mvc:annotation-driven, tx:annotation-driven"s also scan all beans.

I think this is not efficient and not reasonable.

Why scan twice, three times.

Is there any way to avoid this duicate parsing?

Any answer will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, scanning process are not twice, three times as you think.
They are declare for related beans I think.
Please refer to below summarize and find out how differences.

```
<context:annotation-config> 
Declares support for general annotations such as @Required, @Autowired, @PostConstruct, and so on.

<context:component-scan> 
can also do what <context:annotation-config> does but <context:component-scan> also scans packages to find and register beans within the application context.
```

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />  
Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model and 
declares explicit support for annotation-driven MVC controllers (i.e. @RequestMapping, @Controller, although support for those is the default behaviour), as well as adding support for declrative validation via @Valid and message body marshalling with @RequestBody/ResponseBody.
```

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
You do provide the transaction-manager instace directly within element. annotation-config and component-scan won't.
```